# having troubles with importing sqlite to android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-logcat

I'm trying to import sqlite database to my android app. I saw the solution codes of another question here.

I tried to do it but getting **`unfortunately application has stopped`** error.

How can I fix it ?

Here are the logcats:

```
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092): java.lang.Error: ErrorCopyingDataBase
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.nasozby.marifetname.Db.createDataBase(Db.java:48)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.nasozby.marifetname.Adapter.createDatabase(Adapter.java:28)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.nasozby.marifetname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-09 13:05:14.932: E/AndroidRuntime(1092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: from where are you copying it post code

Comment: Make sure you're providing a correct path to your database (check that its name is correct and it is present in the assets folder)

Comment: Path is correct. i checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to ship an initial DB file with your app, then it needs to go in the "assets" dir and get copied over at start (if it does not already exist).

Here is a simple way I have handled this in the past, this code is part of my `SQLiteOpenHelper` (which fires off `createDatabase` in the ctor):

```
private void createDatabase() {
  if (!databaseExists()) {
     Log.i(TAG, "OpenHelper createDatabase, database does NOT exist, will be copied/created...");
     try {
        this.copyDatabase();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "OpenHelper error copying database " + e.getMessage(), e);
     }
  } else {
     Log.d(TAG, "OpenHelper createDatabase, database exists, leaving it alone");
  }
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

  InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME + ".sqlite");

  File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
  dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
  Log.i(TAG, "OpenHelper copyDatabase creating file at path:" + dbFile.getAbsolutePath());

  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile.getAbsolutePath());

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int length;
  while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     os.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }

  os.flush();
  os.close();
  is.close(); 
}

private boolean databaseExists() {
  File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
  return dbFile.exists();
}
```